# @Input not updated on Content Children (custom radio button)

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, angular-changedetection

I'm currently in the process of creating a custom radio group component. I want to make sure that a developer can define the buttons the way they want, so I'm using content projection with `@ContentChildren` so it can look something like this in the end:

```
<custom-radio-group>
    <custom-radio *ngFor="let radio of radios"></custom-radio>
</custom-radio-group>
```

At the moment I am trying to make it so the parent radio group component ensures that the `name` attribute is the same across all its radio button children.
This is done in order to avoid the scenario where a developer tries to apply different names to the radio buttons of the same radio group (since I also want to make it possible for radio buttons to exist outside of a radio group), like the following example:

```
<custom-radio-group>
    <custom-radio [name]="'a'">Option 1</custom-radio>
    <custom-radio [name]="'b'">Option 2</custom-radio>
    <custom-radio [name]="'c'">Option 3</custom-radio>
    <custom-radio [name]="'d'">Option 4</custom-radio>
</custom-radio-group>
```

For the example above, I want to force the rule where the name of the last radio button is applied across all radio buttons.

In my radio group component I have the following code:

```
export class CustoRadioGroupComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    @ContentChildren(CustomRadioComponent) radioButtons!: QueryList<CustomRadioComponent>

    name!: string;

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        if (this.radioButtons) {
            this.updateRadioButtonNames();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ensure integrity of the group name
     * Any dev may try to apply different names to the buttons of a group
     * Make sure that only the last name is propagated
     */
     updateRadioButtonNames() {
        this.name = this.radioButtons.last.name;
        this.radioButtons.forEach((radio, index, radioButtons) => {
            if (index !== radioButtons.length - 1) {
                radio.name = this.name;
                radio._markForCheck();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And for the radio button itself, I have:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'custom-radio',
    styleUrls: ['./custom-radio.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './custom-radio.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush 
}) export class CustomRadioComponent {

    /** Name attribute of the input radio */
    @Input() name!: string;

    constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    _markForCheck() {
        // console.log(this.name); ---> prints "d" 3 times, as expected
        this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    }

    ...
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

custom-radio.component.ts

....
<input type="radio" [name]="name" ...>
....
```

The issue I'm facing currently is that even though I am successfully updating the `name` property of the radio buttons from the parent radio group component, these changes are not being reflected in the DOM, as you can see below:

[image]

I know the `name` is being updated, but I can't make it reflect in the DOM. What am I missing here?

I suspect some possible causes might be:

- `ngAfterContentInit` hook might be called before the initialisation of the radio buttons;
- Change detection might not detect an object property change (in `radio.name = this.name`), but instead only an object identity change.

Comment: You has an `@Input` "name" not an `attribute` "name". In **custom-radio.html** you can use [attr.name]="name" or [name]="name" or inject the ElementRef in constructor and use setAttribute like: `this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('name',"my_name")` if you want to add the attribute to custom-radio

Comment: Yes sorry, I did mean `@Input` instead of `attribute`. And yes, I do have `<input type="radio" [name]="name">` in the template.

Comment: but then, you should see name in the `<input type="radio" name="a">` (not in "custom-radio")

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. `<input type="radio" name="name">` is the template of the custom-radio component. `this.name` prints `"d"` (3 times, as expected) inside of `_markForCheck()`. I should then see all buttons with `ng-reflect-name="d"` in the DOM, but the value is never updated.